# Is possible that : "SELECT COUNT (*) < SELECT COUNT (VALUE)?"

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Can the result value `SELECT COUNT (*)` be smaller than the value `SELECT COUNT (VALUE)`?

And why? Explain the answer please.

Comment: No. `select count(*)` counts the total of all records. `select count([value])` counts a subset of records. The latter count can only be less or the same.

Comment: It could happen if you do the queries some moments apart, and more rows have been added to the table in the meantime. Other than that, no.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT(*)` counts every record, while `COUNT(value)` only takes in account non-null values. For a given dataset, `COUNT(*)` cannot be smaller than `COUNT(value)`, however it may be greater.

Consider the following dataset:

```
val
1
2
null
```

We have 3 records with one whose value is null. Now if we run:

```
select count(*), count(val) from t
```

We would get:

```
count(*) | count(val)
-------: | ---------:
       3 |          2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aeac7acf42c549aedfc7f27ac893bebe)**

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question seems like it's not possible because the select `count(*)` always considers all the lines in the table and the `select count(value)` should be the same or less.

Maybe if you have a `select count (distinct (*))` could be less but in the case that you mention is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No both are same you need to use like this `select count(*), (select count(val/*/1) from t where val IS NOT NULL ) from t`